# Building Intel XDK with SQLite

Tags: html, sqlite, intel-xdk

This might be a often repeated question. I am a newcomer to the world of mobile and programming in general. I am trying to build an app that uses the native database capabilities within android (sqlite) with Intel XDK (HTML5) as the rendering framework. I don't want it to a web based app, but a complete on the device app.

- Can i code server side on XDK (server side code and database connections)
- If not what should be my way of creating the server side component - build it seperately and somehow package it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As per my knowledge Intel XDK is just your front end, to make a communication with your Master DB (MySQL, MsSQL, etc..) you need to have server side language. You can make use of PHP and it is a light weight server side scripting language, you can run it on XAMPP server.

[Here is useful link.](http://qnimate.com/create-a-intel-xdk-app-with-php-and-mysql-backend/)

To make connection with local (device) DB you don't need server side language and server also. Intel XDK itself providing feature to build the app for android (.apk) and IOS (.ipa)  format.

So far I gone through and got, Intel XDK is providing list of four local database connectivity in client end. Which are

- Local Storage
- Web SQL Storage
- Session Storage
- Indexed DB

  [For more detail refer this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828109/intel-xdk-connecting-your-mobile-app-to-a-database)

I'm not sure about Intel XDK with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
You can work with SQLite in phone gap application.Please use the [link](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git) to the Intel XDK third party plugin. Before that please download the project dependency jar file from [GitHub](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage-dependencies.git) and create the directory with cordova plugin SQLite name and place the file in it, include the jar file. Then try to add the plugin using URL.By this you can easily work with the SQLite in phone gap.

Also you can work with the server-side storage using Phone gap application. please see the [link](http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/) for sample.

Hope all helpful